# DB2 LIKE Operator with a Variable

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am new to DB2 which is running on several IBM iSeries boxes. I'm having some difficulty writing a stored procedure that will select values from a table where a key field begins with the value of a parameter.

Now in MS SQL Server I would write this as:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE fieldB like parm + '%'
```

So for my DB2 proc I have:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE fieldB like parm || '%'
```

I found this syntax not only in the IBM documentation, but in several SO questions and answers. So I understand how to concatenate the wildcard character to the parameter value.

Unfortunately, when I run my CREATE PROCEDURE statement I receive the following error:

> [SQL0104] Token PARM was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR NOT CCSID NORMALIZED.

I've even tried doing the following as well:

```
SET [*some declare variable*] = parm|| '%'
```

and

```
SET srch = CONCAT(parm, '%');
```

As well as using the CONCAT function in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE fieldB like CONCAT(parm, '%');
```

Each returning the same error.

So what might I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do you know what version your system is on?

Comment: Yes. Most are running V7R2 but there is at least one that is running V6R1. Eventually all systems will be on V7R2, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work fine...without your code I can't tell exactly what you are doing wrong...

Note you have to explicitly declare cursor to return results set in Db2.  Since you aren't using SELECT INTO, I assume your select returns multiple rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cwilt.myproc(IN parm char(128))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE myRS cursor with return to client for
          select table_name
          from systables
          where table_name like trim(parm) concat '%';

        open myRS;

    END;

call cwilt.myproc(char('SYP'));
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Also I realized my input was 11 characters so I did have to trim it for the match to work.

Comment: Assuming the user could type 11 characters in, you probably want to declare a variable of 12+ so that there's room for the '%'...otherwise you might get a run time error.

Comment: Is there a way to use ? to parameterize (avoid SQL injection)
For example, 
open myRs using :parm

Answer (score 0):

Try SELECT field FROM table WHERE fieldB like ? || '%'

I have used this on my iSeries and it should work according to IBM documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0020295.html

Comment: Thank you. However, it may have been the way I was updating my proc. I was using ALTER PROCEDURE to test various changes. Yet when I dropped the proc and then used CREATE PROCEDURE, there was no errors.

Comment: While parameter markers work for what I call "in-line" SQL statements, they do not work in stored procedures